# Wick rotation graphically

Tags: complex-numbers, regularization, wick-rotation

We have to evaluate

$$i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) dt.$$

We can make a change of variable $t\mapsto -i\tau$, which results in

$$\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty} f(-i\tau) d\tau.$$

If we now multiply the argument of $f$ by $i$, as well as the limits of integration, we will be rotating the function in the complex plane clockwise, as well as the path of integration (which is a straight line), getting

$$\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}f(\tau)d\tau=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\tau)d\tau.$$

The first step changes the space of representation of the function, where the axes of $\tau$-space are rotated 90º with respect to those of $t$-space. And the second step rotates the function and path of integration.

On these graphs we could imagine the integrals shown. The first one, in the first plot would integrate over $\mathrm{Re}\{t\}$ from left to right. In the second, the second integral would integrate over $\mathrm{Im}\{\tau\}$ from left to right following the same path, we see that the integrals are equivalent. The third one would be followed over $\mathrm{Re}\{\tau\}$ from bottom to top.

[image]

The first and third integrals differ by a factor $-i$ except for which they are identical in form, and thus should yield identical results (I guess that this could mean that $-ia = a \Rightarrow a=0$, pointing that all this is not even wrong).

Is this the expected form of the Wick rotation? Does this even make sense? Is this how the Wick rotation works (in flat time)?

I fear that in multiplying the argument of $f$ and the limits of integration by $i$, the path of integration crosses the poles, making all of this absurd.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/489468/2451